# "Primefaces is undefined" Only in IE11 from remote connection

Tags: primefaces, internet-explorer-11

My web application works ok from my local Glassfish server (localhost:8080/App) in every browser, and also in Chrome and Firefox from the remote production server (remoteserver:8080/App).

But, when I try to access the application on the remote server using IE11, the console shows these errors:

```
Archivo: Personalator-1.0-SNAPSHOT
SCRIPT1028: Se esperaba un identificador, una cadena o un número
Archivo: primefaces.js, Línea: 17, Columna: 13994
SCRIPT5009: 'PrimeFaces' no está definido
Archivo: pfCalendarEs.js, Línea: 1, Columna: 1
SCRIPT5009: 'PrimeFaces' no está definido
Archivo: Personalator-1.0-SNAPSHOT, Línea: 27, Columna: 9706
SCRIPT5009: 'PrimeFaces' no está definido
Archivo: Personalator-1.0-SNAPSHOT, Línea: 51, Columna: 6727
SCRIPT5009: 'PrimeFaces' no está definido
Archivo: Personalator-1.0-SNAPSHOT, Línea: 51, Columna: 7264
SCRIPT5009: 'PrimeFaces' no está definido
Archivo: Personalator-1.0-SNAPSHOT, Línea: 38, Columna: 201
```

The first error translates as "Identifier expected, string or number". The rest translate as "PrimeFaces is undefined".

Everything works fine if I try to access using the IE11 installed in the remote server, so it looks like the problem is the remote URL.

Comment: I have the same identical issue. Did you solve in the meanwhile?

Comment: Not really. It was a small internal project for my company: I am the only developer and it is for less than ten users, so I convinced everybody to switch to a decent browser.